# Evaluation of limit at negative infinity is wrong

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

I tried to raise $x$ to the square and get:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \sqrt\frac{x^2}{{x^2+1}}$$

afterwards, as I divide the numerator and denominator by $x^2$ I get

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac1{x^2}}}$$

now after I set $x$ to minus infinity I get $1$. The answer is wrong though.It should be $-1$ as written in the answers.

Any guidance on how to solve it or directions to where I am mistaken will be appreciated.

Comment: changing $x=-y$ will do

Comment: Here you should be interested in negative values of $x$ only. Do you see why? When $x<0$ we have $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$. Try that!

Comment: Close to being [a duplicate of this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1185222/11619). IMHO users should check with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2%2B1%7D%7D%24%2C%20%24x%5Cto-%5Cinfty%24&p=1) before posting answers to obviously standard questions.

Comment: @user6394019  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

> $$\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{(x^2)+1}}$$
>
> I tried to raise x to the square and get:
>
> $$\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \sqrt\frac{x^2}{{(x^2)+1}}$$

So basically you replaced $x$ by $\sqrt{x^2}$ but these two expressions are only equal if $x$ is *positive*; $\sqrt{x^2}$ is positive (as it is the result of a square root) so for negative $x$, it cannot be equal to $x$.

You have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ so for $x<0$, you have $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ and you could replace $x$ by $-\sqrt{x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

You may write
$$
\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \left(\frac{x}{|x|}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}\right)
$$ then observe that, as $x<0$, we have
$$
\frac{x}{|x|}=-1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The best way in these cases to avoid mistakes with sign or to check the result is change $x=-y\to \infty$ then

$$\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\lim \limits_{y \to \infty} -\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}=-1
$$